# Changing rgba values using JavaScript and querySelector

Tags: javascript, css

Lets say I have a CSS class:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

I want to change the rgba value to (0, 0, 0, 0.2)

I want to do this WITHOUT jQuery, and I want to use the querySelector in JavaScript.

So, if I have

```
var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
```

How do I use this to change the background-color value?

I've tried:

```
overlay.background = '(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
```

and

```
overlay.backgroundColor = '(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
```

Comment: Well, just like in the CSS, you need to reference `rgba` before the parenthesis. So, `overlay.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`;`. Note I've also added the `style` accessor, since that is also required.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "style"

Should look like this in vanilla JS.

document.querySelector('.overlay').style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';

Comment: Well, you are missing the `rgb`.